# Filo I/O operations from SD card in Xilinx Zynq ZCU102

Tags: file-io, arm, xilinx, zynq, xilinx-edk

I'm using a Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC ZCU102 Evaluation Kit. I want to run a C++ program in the Xilink SDK tool(running on a Windows machine) that can do Filo I/O operations on a binary file stored in the SD card in the Zync board. I have the command line tool(xsct) setup. My questions are as follows:

1. What are the commands that I have to execute in XSCT tool to mount the SD card?
2. Once the SD card is mounted, how can I query for the SD card drive(whether C:\ or D:\ drive)?

> Edit: The following Xilinx thread suggests that no mounting procedure
>   is required. In this case, I'd like to know how the SD card drive can
>   be identified and the information about the files contained therein
>   can be displayed in the XCST terminal.
>
> https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/Filo-I-O-operations-from-SD-card-in-Xilinx-Zynq-ZCU102/m-p/851582/highlight/false#M45325

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse two different systems.

In simple terms, SD card when inserted in MPSoC-board is accessible to the processor running on the MPSoC-board. The code running on that board will initialize it and access its contents.

XSCT is just a command line tool. It allows to perform the tasks using commands that are also possible using SDK GUI. Go through this [link](https://www.xilinx.com/html_docs/xilinx2018_1/SDK_Doc/xsct/intro/xsct_introduction.html) to understand what XSCK really is.

You can accomplish what you are saying by running PetaLinux on MPSoC and accessing the card using simple open,read,write,close functions by writing a C or C++ program that will run on PetaLinux.

A more difficult approach would be to make a bare-metal (standalone) program with SD-card driver and file-system code in it to access the SD-card